# How to account for scaling, translating, and rotating in canvas mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, canvas, css-transforms

I'm working on an app which requires scaling (by way of `style.width`, not `scale(...)`), translating (`translate(x, y)`) and rotating (e.g. `rotate(90deg)`) a canvas element. I need to then calculate the proper mouse click positions on the canvas. That is, I need to make it so that the ends of lines actually appear where the user clicked. Right now, when I try to incorporate the translation, my calculations come out off by a little bit, which you can see when by clicking twice in the demo canvas below.

Part of what confuses me is which order I should do the untranslating, unrotating, and unscaling in to produce the correct result.

Demo code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

var scaleX = 0.5;
var scaleY = 0.5;
var rot = 1;
var dispWidth = (canvas.width * scaleX);
var dispHeight = (canvas.height * scaleY);
var xlateX = Math.floor((dispHeight - dispWidth) / 2);
var xlateY = Math.floor((dispWidth - dispHeight) / 2);

var transform = "translate(" + xlateX + "px, " + xlateY + "px) rotate(" + (rot * 90) + "deg)";
canvas.style.width = dispWidth + "px";
canvas.style.height = dispHeight + "px";
canvas.style.transform = transform;

var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var stack = [];
canvas.onclick = function (e) {
  
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log('rect', rect.left, rect.top);
  
    // position within canvas, ignoring scroll
    var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
    var y = e.clientY - rect.top;
    console.log('original', x, y);
  
    // scale
    x /= scaleX;
    y /= scaleY;
    console.log('scaled', x, y);
    
    // translate
    x -= xlateX;
    y -= xlateY;
    console.log('translated', x, y);
    
    var tmp;
    switch (rot % 4) {
        case 1:
            tmp = x;
            x = y;
            y = canvas.height - tmp;
            break;
        case 2:
            y = canvas.height - tmp;
            x = canvas.width - tmp;
            break;
        case 3:
            tmp = y;
            y = x;
            x = canvas.width - tmp;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    console.log('rotated', x, y);
    
    stack.push({x: x, y: y});
    if (stack.length > 1) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(stack[0].x, stack[0].y);
        context.lineTo(stack[1].x, stack[1].y);
        context.stroke();
        stack = [];
    }
};
```

```html
Click once to start a line. Click again to finish it.
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Why are you doing it with css? It would be much simpler if you changed the canvas width/height property and applied the transform to the context matrix.

Comment: @Kaiido The app I spoke of above is overlaying user-drawn content onto a native img element. When the user rotates the img element, the rotation and translation is done with CSS, so the actual canvas element has to rotate to match. It probably would have been easier to put both the canvas and img inside another container which itself is transformed (would that work?), but that would require changing more of the existing app than I thought prudent at the time. I may try that approach later.

Comment: Well IMO the easiest way is to drawn everything on a canvas and use canvas' methods to do the transforms. Anyhow it's done rn, it shouldn't be impossible to modify the script that changes the css so that it changes context matrix instead.

Comment: Use a transformation matrix to keep track of the accumulated scales, translations & rotations. Here's a nice script by Simon Sarris. It was written to track canvas element transformations but it works equally well to track CSS transformations: https://github.com/simonsarris/Canvas-tutorials/blob/master/transform.js